# Is it possible to run two ws implementations with one Endpoint?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, endpoints

I have two webservices implementations that shares some namespaces(Uses same objects - object C in example). 
I whant to publish it so

1) There will be shared generated objects for the client side (the same object C stub)

2) I can run booth webservices on one port and access them just changing url like bellow

http://localhost:6690/WS/A?wsdl
http://localhost:6690/WS/B?wsdl

```
package a.wsdl.xxx.com;
@WebService(targetNamespace = "a.wsdl.xxx.com", serviceName = "A", name = "A")
public class A{
    @WebMethod
    public C a(){...}
}
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------

```
package a.wsdl.xxx.com;   
@WebService(targetNamespace = "b.wsdl.xxx.com", serviceName = "B", name = "B")
public class B{
    @WebMethod
    public C b(){...}
}
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------

```
package xxx.com; 
public class C{
 String s; 
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I just created two war files greeting1.war and greeting2.war. Each of them implements a hello-world interface as shown below, only class names are different `Greeting1` and `Greeting2`. Then I deployed both to jboss. Both are accessible via http://localhost:8080/greeting1?wsdl and http://localhost:8080/greeting2?wsdl

```
package my.webservice;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

@WebService
public class Greeting1 {
   @WebMethod
   public String greetClient(String user)
   {
      return "hello " + user;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Two or more applications can't listen same port.